# Magento2: Product detail page redirect to catalog search page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

While upgrade Magento2.3.2 to Magento2.3.3, we got some error in product detail page. If i click product detail page automatically redirect to catalog search page.

Eg:www.example.com/sameple-test => www.example.com?g=sameple-test

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried re-saving categories?

Comment: @Sondre, this is product page.

Comment: By re-saving categories, you trigger url rewrite for products in that specific category.

Comment: After re-saving of categories, got same error displayed. (reindex and cache deploy)

Comment: @Sondre, new product also same error

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: @Sondre, no error showing automatically search redirecting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104361/discussion-between-soundararajan-m-and-sondre).

Comment: Hello @Soundararajanm Please refer link https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls and run below commnds  

# Regenerate url for all products and the global store
php bin/magento regenerate:product:url

# Regenerate url for products with id (1, 2, 3, 4) for store 1
php bin/magento regenerate:product:url -s1 1 2 3 4

Hope help you.

Comment: Hi @MohitPatel, after follow this https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls getting same error.

Comment: Hello @Soundararajanm Please refer this https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/url-redirect-product-automatic.html Hope help you.